# Compute $\int_{0}^{\pi}d\varphi \ \hat{\varphi}.$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

From an electrostatics problem I got to the integral

$$\int_{0}^{\pi}d\varphi \ \hat{\rho}\tag1$$

in cylindrical coordinates $(\rho,\varphi,z)$. Since it's essential to get the answer in cartesian coordinates $(x,y,z)$ I need to convert my $\hat{\rho}-$direction into cartesian form. My book suggests that we can rewrite $\hat{\rho}=\hat{x}\cos\varphi+\hat{y}\sin{\varphi}$ which will lead to

$$\int_{0}^{\pi}(\hat{x}\cos\varphi+\hat{y}\sin{\varphi}) \ d\varphi \ = 2\hat{y}. \tag2$$

Can anyone explain why $\hat{\rho}=\hat{x}\cos\varphi+\hat{y}\sin{\varphi} \ ?$ And lets say I had $\hat{\varphi}$ or $\hat{z}$ instead of $\hat{\rho},$ how would I convert these into cartesian?

Answer (score 3):

This is simply because $\hat{\rho}$ points radially outward from the $\hat{z}$-axis.  Since it points radially outward, you can project it to the $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{y}$ directions, and since $\varphi$ is the angle measured off the positive $\hat{x}$-axis, this gives you

$$
\hat{\rho} \;\; =\;\; \cos\varphi \hat{x} + \sin\varphi\hat{y}.
$$

Converting from cylindrical to Cartesian won't affect $\hat{z}$.  Converting $\hat{\varphi}$, note that this is the direction of increasing values of $\varphi$, hence it is tangent to the unit circle as you trace a path going counterclockwise.  Some basic trig and planar geometry should convince you that
$$
\hat{\varphi} \;\; =\;\; -\sin\varphi \hat{x} + \cos\varphi \hat{y}.
$$

Equivalently, you can think of this as the unit vector pointing out from the curve $\gamma(t) = (\cos t, \sin t)$.

Comment: All I needed to know. Thanks!